# getting data as the page loads

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm trying to get data back after an element is ready in the DOM.  I'm trying to use the load function from JQUERY but I get a message .load() is not a function.

Is there a best practice when using ajax to get data for an element (in my case a div) during a page load?  I'm using ASP.NET and calling a webmethod in code behind.

Here is my ajax/jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      $(function () {

          $("[id$=divArea]").load()(function () {

              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "apage.aspx/Role",
                  data: "{}",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  async: false,
                  success: function (response) {
                      alert("got data from Role");
                  },
                  error: function (data) {
                      alert("failed to get data from Role");
                  }

              });               

          });

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: .load only works on elements that actually load something such as iframes images and the window. what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Is it possible to use `$object.load()` on a jQuery $object that matches more than one element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(document).ready() is for calling code once the DOM is ready - therefore, if I have understood you correctly, you don't need to include `$("[id$=divArea]").load()(function () {`

It should work like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(function () {

          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "apage.aspx/Role",
              data: "{}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              async: false,
              success: function (response) {
                  alert("got data from Role");
              },
              error: function (data) {
                  alert("failed to get data from Role");
              }

          });               

      });

});
```

By the way - it was probably a paste error, but you also omitted the `$(document).ready` closing `});` in the code you posted.

Comment: on reflection, you don't even need the $(function () {}); wrapper around your ajax call - you can just make the ajax call directly in the $(document)ready(function(){})

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem it's the code itself, try the code like this

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $("[id$=divArea]").load('apage.aspx/Role',function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
             var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
             $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        })

});
```